# Using just CSS, crop .img keeping aspect without distortion

Tags: css, image, crop, aspect-ratio

I have an image that has been placed inside a div. The div is 600 width and has a variable height.

I want my image to sit at the top of the div. If I make the width 590 the issue is that the image is then too high in terms of design and it looks too dominant on the page (because its ratio is roughly 4:3 etc).

So I want to make the image 590 by 200. If i use...

```
.img { 
width: 590px;
max-height: 200px;
}
```

...then the image sits inside the div exactly how I want it. However, the photo itself is squashed and distorted into the 590 by 200. How can I ensure that the image just crops within that size and has no distortion?

I have no access to the html so cant add a wrapper around it either unfortunately... This will need to be done only by editing the CSS class .img.

EDIT - Andy is right, negative margins are the only way I can get this to work. Thank you Andy.

Comment: The closest you can get without a container is using a negative margin-top and margin-right

Comment: Can you set the image as a background? If so, then I might have a solution.

Comment: Given your constraints, I think your only shot is the [`clip` property](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/clip). Unfortunately, the element must be absolutely positioned.

Comment: Yeah, the Clip seemed good but I can't make the image absolutely positioned. Thanks though.

Comment: I assume you can't add javascript (that doesn't modify the DOM) either? If you can turn the image into a div with background (via :after{:content), then there are CSS properties that can do it. I still don't know how to supply the image URL to the background except by injecting CSS from javascript.

Comment: Andy is right, negative margins are the only way I can get this to work. Thank you Andy.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that simply by editing the css. You need to put the image as background-image in HTML

```
<div class="cover">
    <div style="background-image: url(http://img.youtube.com/vi/6WNyczNYsc0/0.jpg); " class="video-thumbnail"></div>
</div>
```

and using `background-size: cover;` in css

**CSS**

```
​.cover {
    width: 590px;
    height: 200px;
}
.video-thumbnail {
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/q4qEG/)

In the demo I placed the background-position as center.

Comment: Adding a wrapper is not possible either.

Comment: "You cannot do that simply by editing the css" Unfortunately I think you are right. I can't access the HTML to create a wrapper or change the image to a background image. I'll keep playing but thought I'd ask in case someone had some magic...

Comment: Yeah. Without editing the HTML, all other solutions will make the image distorted!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
.img { 
width: auto;
max-height: 200px;
}
```

warning: auto width doesn't work in IE7 (and I'm not sure about IE8). You may have to use js solutions for backward compatibility.

Comment: then the image is too narrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this image into div background-image style, and then use CSS3 style - background-size: cover

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't edit the div style or html. I can only access the CSS for .img

Comment: @user1325308 there is a clear idea here: try playing with the background-image properties. There is a lot of potential in them.