# What are the solutions for cropping an img in css, without a wrapper or distortion?

Tags: html, css, image, crop

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582051/using-just-css-crop-img-keeping-aspect-without-distortion), I was wondering if there are any new solutions for cropping an `<img>` in css, without distorting it, whilst maintaining its aspect ratio (without adding a wrapper).

For example: lets say we have an `<img src="#">`. Would it be possible to crop this image when it reaches `min-height:200px;`, without stretching it horizontally, whilst keeping it to `width:100%;`?

Can this be done without a wrapper and javascript, in pure css?

---

- I have read in the other question that the only option would be with negative margins, but that solution is only hinted at and not actually explained.
- Furthermore, another possible solution could be by using `clip`, but that would take the element out of the document flow, which would mean that any solution using `clip` would also have to reposition the element at its original place (whilst pushing the other content away).
- Another answer in the linked question hinted at using generated content, but I don't see how this would work as generated content cannot insert html (only text), as far as I know.

Comment: CSS is meant to control HOW content is displayed, not WHAT content (or be able to manipulate the content). I don't think you can actually crop in CSS (unless there's something new in CSS3 that I don't know about). You'll only be able to make it appear cropped. Why do you have to do it without a wrapper?

Comment: @Inspire48 I thought that would be the appropriate way. Or would using the `<figure>` tag to crop it also be ok? Because the img I want to crop is a main part of content, not an aside. So I thought `figure` would be out of the question, and using a wrapper just is something I thought I should avoid.

Comment: Stop using the word crop. Crop is what you do in PhotoShop! not with CSS.

Comment: @MarcAudet, then what would you call it? You know what I mean right?

Comment: It is not clear if you want to the image to fill its parent container (resizing) or if you want to show only a portion of it (clip).  You are asking to set the max or min height of the image, but the 100% width needs to be calculated with respect to something, namely, the parent container.  So without discussing the parent container, it is hard to propose a meaningful solution.

Answer (score 0):

i think the only (and simplest) way to do this is by putting the image as background of a div or an img.

let's say we have [this](http://casafamilyday.org/familyday/files/media/Family%20of%204%20outside_new%20homepage%20photo.jpg) image and we want to crop just the face of the man on the right.

we can do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="img"></div>  
<!-- OR -->
<img class="img"/>
```

CSS:

```
.img{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    background-image:url(http://casafamilyday.org/familyday/files/media/Family%20of%204%20outside_new%20homepage%20photo.jpg);
    background-position:300px 0;
}
```

[FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/F3Du4/1/)
in this way you can easily crop an image using just one element on your html, and it's easy to import images dinamically by replacing the `background-image` property with javascript.